# "underlineColorAndroid is not a valid style property" error in react-native android app

Tags: android, react-native

I want to remove the underline style from my `TextInput` component. I used the `underlineColorAndroid` property, but it's not working.

[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`underlineColorAndroid` is a prop of `TextInput`, not a React Native style.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
<TextInput underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} value={this.state.text} />
```

Comment: Does this also work for Input fields? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63656389/remove-input-underline-with-underlinecolorandroid